# VBA if conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I wrote if condition which is shown below, it looks for value "Current Status:" in row A  and copy B value from that row to other sheet, if not not found "0" is placed in a cell, it works fine. Sometimes value "Current Status:" might be in a different cell than A18, it might show up in the range from A16 to A20, how can I modify that code to find it within the range and copy corresponding value?

```
If ws.Range("A18") = "Current Status:" Then
    .Range("V" & NewRow) = ws.Range("B18")
     Else
        .Range("V" & NewRow) = "0"
      End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your code in a `For` loop... or use `VLookup` like Scotty suggested. It's basically the same thing. A `For` loop is more flexible but less optimized (`VLookup` is faster). They both run on the order of fractions of a μs/cell.

```
For Each c In Range("A16:A20")
    If c.Value2 = "Current Status:" Then
        .Range("V" & NewRow) = c.Offset(0, 1)
        Exit For
    Else
        .Range("V" & NewRow) = "0"
    End If
Next
```

If using a `For` loop, this is a little bit more code than what's above but a better structure...

```
'Define a value holder variable where it's scope makes sense
Dim NewValue As String

'... other code here ...

'Default: NewValue = ""
NewValue = ""
For Each c In Range("A16:A20")
    If c.Value2 = "Current Status:" Then
        NewValue = c.Offset(0, 1)
        'Exit For is optional in this case. It matters if
        'there are multiple matches... do you want first or last result?
        Exit For
    End If
Next
'Assign NewValue to cell
.Range("V" & NewRow) = NewValue
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it shows how much is there to learn yet... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Vlookup:

```
.Range("V" & NewRow) = "0"
On Error Resume Next
.Range("V" & NewRow) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Current Status:", ws.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
On Error GoTo 0
```

This will put 0 in the cell then try to replace it with the value returned from the vlookup.  If `"Current Status:"` is not found in column A on `ws` then it will throw an error and be ignored leaving `0` in the cell.

If the value is found it will return the value in Column B and put that in place of the `0`

Comment: and u8it codes work like a charm, thank you. I just found out that in some cases I might have another row with  cell containing "Current Status:" value...Is there a way to modify that code to force it to ignore first found row and retrieve second occurrence if I need it? or maybe it is easier if the second value is found to put it cell in the next column    { ws.Range("A19") }

Comment: There are many ways, try some research and come back with a new question showing what you have tried.